# Ads Targeting & Facebook Ads API

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

I am submitting the following target criteria:

```
{countries":["US"],
"cities":{"name":"Gilbert, AZ"},
"zips":[],
"regions":[],
"radius":0,
"locals":null,
"keywords":[],
"user_adclusters":[],
"interested_in":null,
"genders":null,
"age_min":25,
"age_max":0}
```

The error I'm getting back is:

```
(Exception - #0) Invalid Cities.
```

Can someone help me?

Thanks!
Eric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try including the ID of the city too:

(the 'key' you get back from the search endpoint)

e.g.

`countries":["US"],"cities":[{"id": 2413131,"name":"Gilbert, AZ"},{//SOME OTHER CITY}],"zips":[],"regions":[],"radius":0,"locals":null,"keywords":[],"user_adclusters":[],"interested_in":null,"genders":null,"age_min":25,"age_max":0}`

Sometimes supplying the name only doesn't work

Comment: {"countries":["US"],"cities":{"id":"2413131","name":"Gilbert, AZ"},"zips":[],"regions":[],"radius":0,"locals":null,"keywords":[],"user_adclusters":[],"interested_in":null,"genders":null,"age_min":25,"age_max":0}  Same error - Should cities be surronded by []?  The C# code is essentially a Dictionary<string, string>.

Comment: Sorry, yes, i think that was a mistake on my part - updating now

Comment: Thanks Igy, I'll work on trying to fix up the serialization code and try to determine why it's not working as expected.

Comment: Try it as a direct call to the graph API (via the graph explorer or CURL, maybe?) - i think my updated code should work

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!!  It worked!  Thanks so much Igy!!!  BTW: I wanted to tell you thank you, you guys are doing some AMAZING work on the FB API, thank you for spending time out of your busy day to help a n00b like me. :)  Thank you very much.  Now if only I could vote your answer as, the answer. :D